# Is there a way to confirm a package-lock.json actually resolves all dependencies in a package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

We want to add an automated check to our CI server that would prevent code from getting committed that updates a dependency in `package.json` but does not update the resolved dependency in `package-lock.json`.

This could happen if, for example, someone updated a dependency in `package.json` manually but ran `npm install` instead of `npm update` (`npm install` favors `package-lock.json`, if present). Or it could happen even if someone runs the correct `npm` command when updating a dependency but then forgets to commit the resulting changes to `package-lock.json`. We try to watch for these things in code review, but an automated check would definitely be better. Is there any `npm` command that does this?

Here's an example to illustrate.

**Before**:

```
// package.json
{
    "lodash": "~3.1.0"
}

// package-lock.json
{
    "dependencies": {
       "lodash": {
           "version": "3.1.3"
       }
    }
}
```

Someone updates `package.json` but forgets to commit the change to `package-lock.json`.

**After:**

```
// package.json
{
    "lodash": "~3.2.0"
}

// package-lock.json (not changed)
{
    "dependencies": {
       "lodash": {
           "version": "3.1.3"
       }
    }
}
```

Now `package-lock.json` no longer reflects a valid set of dependency resolutions for the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 10):

Running [`npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) seems to do this for you because it throws an error for discrepancies between [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) and its [lock](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks). In a node script you could do this using node's [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) or `.execSync`. Async seems cleaner if you want to include helpful messages:

```
const cp = require("child_process");
const verify = () => cp.exec("npm ls", error => {
  if (error) {
    console.error("Dependency mismatch between package.json and lock. Run: npm install");
    throw error;
  }
  console.log("Dependencies verified =)");
});
```

Or to keep it simple you could just run `npm ls` at some point in your CI before `npm install`.

Comment: If you only care about the differences in the top-level, for example if you're sure no one is going to go into node_modules and update things manually, you could use `npm ls --depth 0`. This would at least cut out some of the output, though I think it still shows discrepancies in nested versions. Also, you can use `--json` for more parse-able output for scripts.

Comment: `--depth 0` (the top level) is already the default when you run without specifying depth.

Answer (score 6):

> ...
>
> Or to keep it simple you could just run npm ls at some point in your CI before npm install.

It doesn't cover case with initial npm install when there are not node_modules (what in case of CI server could be every time)

Use npm ci (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci) available since 5.7.x version.

```
npm ERR! cipm can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's core-js@2.5.7 does not satisfy core-js@^3.0.0-alpha.4
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `npm ci` command. It checks to make sure that the `package.json` and the `package-lock.json` are always in sync.

If they go out of sync, you get an error similar to

```
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's yuglify@2.0.0 does not satisfy yuglify@^2.0.1
```

Comment: It does not update the "version" field of your own package in the package-lock, though.

Comment: For that, I started using https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-lock-utd

Comment: See about `npm ci` behavior change https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5113