# How to check whether package-lock.json out of date?

Tags: node.js, npm

In CI I want to check that package-lock.json is up to date with package.json. To do this I use `npm ci`.

However I found that if I update the main package version in package.json (but forget to do it in package-lock.json) then `npm ci` passes without errors.

What am I missing? How do you check for matching root level version?

Eg:

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {...}
}
```

package-lock.json:

```json
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {...}
}
```

```
> npm ci
> echo $?
0
```

^ this should fail

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to confirm a package-lock.json actually resolves all dependencies in a package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287398/is-there-a-way-to-confirm-a-package-lock-json-actually-resolves-all-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `package-lock-utd` for this (https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-lock-utd).

Simply execute the following in the root of your project:

```
npx package-lock-utd@1.x.x
```

If your `package-lock.json` is not up to date (e.g. because you forgot to run `npm install` after changing the "version" field), the script will exit with a non-zero exit code. I use this check in my CI before running `npm ci` (or `npm install`) because, as you have noticed, `npm ci` does not always fail if `package-lock.json` is not up to date.

Sample GitHub Actions workflow:

```yaml
name: Main Checks

on: [push, pull_request, workflow_dispatch]

jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18

      - name: Check if package-lock.json is up to date
        run: npx --yes package-lock-utd@1.x.x

      # Now, run any command you like. This is just an example.
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Run the linter
        run: npm run lint
```

---

Disclaimer: I am the author of this package.
In the past, I used a small shell script in my CI that would perform this check. However, copying this script from repository to repository seemed like a suboptimal solution, which is why I created this npm package.